# How to prevent specific collection not to delete

Tags: mongodb

I am on windows platform. I have a shell script which delete the whole database when cronjob cal this file.

File is

```
delete.sh

#!/usr/bin/env mongo
mongo 127.0.0.1:27021/test --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

Let's say I have a collection named as "Doctor" Now I don't want to delete that table.

Any idea how to acheive this.

> can we use --excludeCollection here???

Answer (score 1):

There is no such flag. Dropping database means dropping the whole database. If you need at least one collection to remain you need to keep the database. Collections don't exists without a database.

What you can do is to drop collections instead. Use [db.getCollectionNames](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db.getCollectionNames) and drop them one by one excluding the ones you want to keep.

E.g. with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27021/test --eval "db.getCollectionNames().filter(c=>!['Doctor'].includes(c)).forEach(c=>db.getCollection(c).drop())"
```

Or using [getCollectionInfos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos) with query filter:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27021/test --eval "db.getCollectionInfos({name:{$nin: ['Doctor']}}).forEach(({name})=>db.getCollection(name).drop())"
```

You may need to escape the dollar sign in `$nin`. I can't recall how shell scripts work on windows.

Comment: I suggest `getCollectionInfos({ type: "collection", name: { "$ne": "Doctor } }).map(e => e.name)` instead. The `getCollectionNames()` method has no way to filter "views", and you can actually include "query" options through the other method. Noting `drop()` on a view will error.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Are you certain about the error? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/#drop-a-view says opposite.

Comment: I think you're right there. I was probably thinking `getIndexes()` or the like due to running similar things before. ( but probably with the [`listCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) command ) as I know asking for index information on a view will error of course. So of course you *can" drop a view, but then again you probably would not want to if your intention was to re-create the same collection names.